# Grouped Stacked Bar Charts in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Is there any way to create subgroups for stacked bar charts in R? Below is an example of what I'm aiming for.

[Example of What I'm Aiming to Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITkbv.png)

I'm currently using the below code - but I can't figure out how to sub-group the samples (identified by the ID column) by their larger arching group (Sample Site)

ggplot(PFASData, aes(fill=Species, y=value, x=ID)) +
geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")

[Resulting Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7CnJ.png)

Comment: Seems like a facet with 0-width spacing would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example that shows grouping by subgroup (here `cyl`) with stacked bars. By using `scales = "free_x", space = "free_x"` we can get equal width bars within varying-width subgroups.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.character(cyl), wt, fill = as.character(mpg))) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(.~gear, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]